# Regex to delete faulty characters within a csv file to make SplFileObject work correctly in PHP

Tags: php, regex, csv, character-encoding, splfileobject

I try to parse a csv file in PHP via `SplFileObject`. Sadly `SplFileObject` stucks sometimes if there are erroneous invisible characters in the text. The function detects a quote instead of skipping or read it as normal character while iterating over the lines in the csv file.
The screenshot below is from Textwrangler:

[image]

I also copied it from Textwrangler here (invisible char should be between "forgé." and "Circa"):

```
Fer forgé.� Circa
```

My code (SplFileObject part):

```
$splFile = new \SplFileObject($file);
$splFile->setFlags(\SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE | \SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY | \SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD | \SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$splFile->setCsvControl(",", '"', '"');
```

I tried to figure out which charset the csv file has via `file -I my.csv`. Output: `my.csv: application/octet-stream; charset=binary`. That is a weird result as the file is readable via Textwrangler and is therfore **NOT** binary. I also read another csv generated in the same way and the output is as expected: `second.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8`. The tool used to generate the csv files is called [Visual Web Ripper](http://visualwebripper.com) (tool for crawling web pages).

How I can determine which character this upside-down question mark is (it seems not to be the spanish upside down question mark - maybe just a placeholder inserted by Textwrangler)?
How can I delete this character and all "invalid" characters in my csv file? Is there a regular expression which matches every character, number, sign (punctuation and other textual symbols) which is in fact a real character and leave out something like in the example above? I am looking for an unicode-safe regular expression (need to preserve german umlauts, french, russian, chinese, japan and korean characters as well). Alternatively: How can I convert a csv file with `charset=binary` to **UTF-8**?

**Edit:**
If I open it via `nano` editor it shows `forgé.^@ Circa`. After a quick search it seems to be a NUL character or \u0000 (see comments and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character for reference).

**Edit 2:**
I digged a little more into it: It seems that there is a problem with the `$splFile->current()` function, which reads a line at the current file pointer. The line gets truncated after the `NUL` character (no matter if I try to read it via `SplFileObject::READ_CSV` or just as normal string (without `SplFileObject::READ_CSV` parameter)).

Comment: It shows as a standard space when I copy your text https://regex101.com/r/W1utdB/1

Comment: I guess the reason is that there is no character in the unicode charset table which represents the faulty byte sequence (which represents the faulty character)? I can even see a strange sign at this page in the post of my question.

Comment: Yes you are probably right. I'm just saying it's hard to help when we don't know what character it is.

Comment: The corrupt character is represented as `fffd` if converted to hex whereas a space is represented by `20`. F. e. at http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.htm

Comment: Maybe that is a solution? Concert to hex, remove fffd and convert back?

Comment: Have to correct my previous comment: `fffd` is the representation of the so called "replacement character" as stated by https://unicode-table.com/en/FFFD/ (which is rendered by the browser if an invalid char should be rendered). So I think that is not the originally inserted character in the csv but a browser-converted thing.
I tried to convert the specific character directly to hex via php. Result was `00`. I also looked into the ascii / unicode table: `00` stands for `NUL` (https://unicode-table.com/en/0000/). Well, now I just have to figure out how to delete that character via regex.

Comment: I can't help you much. In other cases a question like this would probably be locked since the problem can't be reproduced. But I think this can be have value for SO and I hope the question will stay open til you can answer your own question. I'll definitely upvote this as I think it can help others with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to omit the `SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE` parameter. I also checked if the `NUL` character is present: It is present, but it is now considered as part of the text value of the specific column in the csv and is **NOT** detected as quote or column enclosure.

Of course you have to filter out empty lines by yourself now with f. e. something like:

```
$splFileObject = new \SplFileObject();
$splFileObject->setFlags(\SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY | \SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD | \SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

$columns = $splFileObject->current();
if (count($columns) === 1 && array_key_exists(0, $columns) && $columns[0] === NULL) {
   // empty csv line
}
```